# ClassNotFoundException for all JSF annotated classes on GlassFish 4.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I'm getting a lot of SEVERE log entries when using PrimeFaces 5.1 in a EAR setup with Glassfish 4.1: ClassNotFoundExceptions are logged for each annotated JSF class, even PrimeFaces classes (renderers, validators, converters, etc.). If I remove the PrimeFaces dependency everything works fine (there are still WARNINGs that classes are not found, but no SEVERE log entries). The application however deploys fine and is usable in both cases, I'm just talking about the log entries when deploying the application.

**Environment**

- Mojarra 2.2.7
- PrimeFaces 5.1
- GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

**Setup**

EAR deployment with multiple WAR modules, a JAR module and an EJB module.

**EAR files**

- [EAR with primefaces](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aig0t548kp58rr8/ear-with-primefaces.ear?dl=1)
- [EAR without primefaces](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4z4u29e8sl39t3/ear-without-primefaces.ear?dl=1)

**Log**

```
[2015-02-16T14:32:34.785+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093554785] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class org.primefaces.validate.DoubleRangeValidator, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.validate.DoubleRangeValidator]]

[2015-02-16T14:32:34.786+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093554786] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class org.primefaces.validate.RegexValidator, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.validate.RegexValidator]]

[2015-02-16T14:32:34.788+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093554788] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class org.primefaces.validate.LongRangeValidator, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.validate.LongRangeValidator]]

[2015-02-16T14:32:34.789+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093554789] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class org.primefaces.validate.LengthValidator, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.validate.LengthValidator]]

[2015-02-16T14:32:35.165+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093555165] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unable to load annotated class: com.tsystems.ima.client.presentation.TestConverter]]

[2015-02-16T14:32:35.166+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=416 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1424093555166] [levelValue: 1000] [[

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tsystems.ima.client.presentation.TestConverter
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
        at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
        at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClassList(AnnotationScanner.java:309)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DelegateToGlassFishAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegateToGlassFishAnnotationScanner.java:85)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5932)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: Where is the PrimeFaces JAR placed in the EAR? Problem suggests that you mistakenly placed it in `EAR/lib` instead of `EAR/WAR/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @BalusC It's currently in the WAR module, I'll try moving it to the EAR, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Uh no, web libraries belong in WAR, not in EAR. So if it's already there then it's OK. Do you have any other web libraries in EAR, perhaps JSF itself?

Comment: Ah ok, I misread your comment. You assumed I have it in the EAR, but it's correctly in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @BalusC No, EAR only contains dependencies to WAR, EJB and JAR module. All web and Java EE related stuff has provided scope.

Comment: Hm OK. Exception suggests a (duplicated) JSF or PrimeFaces library loaded by the wrong classloader. That's all I can tell based on it (note: I haven't downloaded and inspected the EARs)

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I was surprised as well that those exceptions appeared when moving from GF 3.1.2.2 to GF 4.1. The provided EARs are basically a minimal setup (EJB module with 1 EJB, WAR module with one CDI bean, the two converters etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Glassfish: [GLASSFISH-20720](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20720)

See also:

- [GLASSFISH-16937](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16937)
- [GLASSFISH-18946](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18946)

There doesn't seem to be a fix right now for Glassfish, but it is fixed in Payara: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/374